# Which adjectives go with the phrase 'strike somebody as (being) something'

Tags: adjectives, phrase-usage

[The longman dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/strike_1) states that we can use '**strike somebody as (being) something**' and 'it strikes somebody **as strange/odd** etc that' to mean that something seems to have a particular quality or feature

> His jokes didn't strike Jack as being very funny.

As I understand, we can always say that something strikes us as strange (odd), and that would sound normal. For example,

> This struck me as *strange* and made me look into the further data in the past.

I wonder which adjectives are well combined with this phrase, besides 'strange', 'odd' and 'funny'? Are all adjectives applicable here?

I took 'unpleasant' as an example:

> The bubbling sound struck me (as) unpleasant. (ok?)

Answer (score 6):

The verb *strike* here doesn't mean much more than *seem*, with an implication that the appearance is 'striking' and perhaps 'immediate' or 'superficial'; so it is possible to conceive circumstances under which practically any adjective might be employed here. I pluck *cardiovascular* off the first text that meets my eye, and I imagine two physicians discussing a chart: one suggests that there are signs of gastrointestinal disease and the other responds

> I don't know about that; these symptoms strike me as cardiovascular.

Comment: Hmm... But it strikes me as being warm today? It struck him as boring? I'm (sincerely) not sure those work. Might there at least tend to be a suggestion of suddenness, intensity, notability?

Comment: @Jim Those work fine for me. You may not be 'struck' by the realization that you are  warm or bored until you have suffered those conditions for some time, or until someone else expresses a contrary characterization. I intended the notions of 'intensity' and 'notability' to be embraced in 'striking', and that of 'suddenness' in 'immediate'.

Comment: Ah. I didn't read your answer carefully enough. I'm loathe to deprive my fans of my opinions for any longer than is necessary. That kind of responsibility can drive a wreckless haste, you see. O.O

Comment: This _strike_ is an intensified _seem_, and shares some of _seem_'s peculiarities: Extraposition (_It seems to/strikes me that `S`_), A-Raising (_He seems to be/strikes me as being harmless_). But the experiencer must be expressed, which is not true for _seem_: _It seems/*strikes that `S`_. Semantically, the metaphor is a blow to one's head -- sudden, unexpected, unignorable, changing one's context permanently. So it makes sense the experiencer would be required.